# Retrofit sempre retornando null no Response

Tags: android, retrofit

A resposta vem com o código 200, ou seja, correta, mas o body fica nulo.

Segue a model:

```
public class MovieModel {
    @SerializedName("imdbID")
    @Expose
    public String idMovie;

    @SerializedName("Title")
    @Expose
    public String titleMovie;

    @SerializedName("Year")
    @Expose
    public String yearMovie ;

    @SerializedName("Poster")
    @Expose
    public String imgMovie;

    public MovieModel() {
    }

    public MovieModel(String idMovie, String titleMovie, String yearMovie, String imgMovie) {
        this.idMovie = idMovie;
        this.titleMovie = titleMovie;
        this.yearMovie = yearMovie;
        this.idMovie = imgMovie;
    }

}
```

API:

```
public interface ApiRetrofitService {

    interface MoviesFutureCallback<T> {

        void onSuccess(T movies);
    }
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://www.omdbapi.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    @GET("?apiKey=ec6483bd")
    Call<MovieResults> getFilmesByName(@Query("t") String movieName);


}
```

Service:

```
ApiRetrofitService serviceapi = ApiRetrofitService.retrofit.create(ApiRetrofitService.class);

public void moviesSearchResult(final Context context, String nameMovie, final ApiRetrofitService.MoviesFutureCallback<MovieResults> callback){
    Call<MovieResults> call = serviceapi.getFilmesByName(nameMovie);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResults>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResults> call, Response<MovieResults> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200){
                try{
                    MovieResults results = response.body();
                    callback.onSuccess(results);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResults> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Results:

```
public class MovieResults {

    @SerializedName("search")
    public List<MovieModel> movies;

    public MovieResults(){}

    public MovieResults(List<MovieModel> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }
}
```

Resposta PostMan:

```
{
    "Title": "Star",
    "Year": "2001",
    "Rated": "NOT RATED",
    "Released": "01 Jun 2001",
    "Runtime": "7 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Short, Comedy",
    "Director": "Guy Ritchie",
    "Writer": "Guy Ritchie, Joe Sweet",
    "Actors": "Clive Owen, Michael Beattie, Toru Tanaka Jr., DTeflon",
    "Plot": "The Driver now carries an arrogant rock star who is visiting a major city (not Pittsburgh as earlier believed). Played by Madonna, this title character wants to get away from her bodyguards...",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "1 win.",
    "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY0NTY2NTUwNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzQxMzg5._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings": [
        {
            "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
            "Value": "7.8/10"
        }
    ],
    "Metascore": "N/A",
    "imdbRating": "7.8",
    "imdbVotes": "6,459",
    "imdbID": "tt0286151",
    "Type": "movie",
    "DVD": "N/A",
    "BoxOffice": "N/A",
    "Production": "N/A",
    "Website": "N/A",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

Resposta no debug Android:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://www.omdbapi.com/?apiKey=ec6483bd&t=Test}
```

Onde está errado? Pois sempre fica nulo.

Comment: Está caindo dentro do onFailure?

Comment: Não. Cai normalmente no onSuccess, mas retorna nulo. Vou editar a resposta que recebo ao utilizar o postman, mas no codigo fica nulo.

Comment: Já experimentou tirar o `@Expose`  e deixar somente o `@SerializedName` ?

Comment: Sim, já experimentei não altera, eu o coloquei por pesquisas pela internet. Não o utiizava

Comment: Mano, acho que é porque no seu json não tem nenhum "search"'... Você está usando @SerializedName("search")...

Comment: Por que na verdade deveria ser um array, e você publicou apenas um objeto. O array deve ter o nome search, caso contrario imagino eu que não vá funcionar mesmo. Se realmente é um objeto, você não pode colocar Call<MovieResults> e sim Call<MovieModel>

Comment: Não tem aquela maozinha na cara do whatsapp. Parece que tem razão, não me retorna mesmo, assim trouxe o card à tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está retornando nulo porque não está acontecendo o parse do body em JSON para o objeto Java.
Baseado no nome do método `Call<MovieResults> getFilmesByName(@Query("t") String movieName);` o retorno deverá ser uma lista de filmes, então o JSON deverá estar em formato de lista também, o que não condiz com o retornado no seu teste com Postman.

Sua requisição à API sempre retornará um único resultado.

Para retornar uma lista, você deve alterar o parâmetro **t** para **s**, conforme a documentação em : http://www.omdbapi.com/

E então, seu JSON ficará assim:

```
{
  "Search": [ 
    {
     "Title": "Star",
     "Year": "2001",
     "Rated": "NOT RATED",
      ...
    }, 
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Ah, altere `@SerializedName("search")` para `@SerializedName("Search")`.